# ImageIO.read cannot read my image in java [Windows]

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, embedded-resource

I'm trying to make an simple GUI. For this purpose I have to put an background image into one of my panels. To do that I've written the following code.

```
public class Display extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage bgPicture;
    public Display() 
    {
        super();

        try 
        {
            bgPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("bg.jpg"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(bgPicture, 0, 0, 800, 700, null);
    }


}
```

I use eclipse and all of my images are in the same directory with my *.java* files (src folder)

However when I run the program I get the following error :

***javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!***

What should I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) in the [tag:embedded-resource] tag.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for reply, but application will not work on my pc, so actually I dont know the path, I put my images to same folder with my src files and I want to access them, how could I do it ?

Comment: *"I put my images to same folder with my src files"* then they are embedded resources and the links that trashgod has suggested would be helpful to solving your problem.  An embedded resource can no longer be accessed as if it were a file on the file system, because it's not.  Instead, consider using something like `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("bg.jpg"));`, assuming the `bg.jpg` is in the same folder/package as the `Display` class

Comment: Then it looks like you have mess in your project. I suspect that you will want to release it as JAR so you probably should avoid `new File("bg.jpg")` which will try to find `bg.jpg` file in current location of terminal. Instead of placing your image directly in `src` folder, place it in same package as one of your classes and use `ClassName.class..getResource(pathRelativeToClassNameOrRootOfProject)`